# Why does my C++ native app present as managed code in the debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

While struggling to get the VS2019 remote debugger to load symbols, I noticed when I go to attach the debugger in VS, the process displays as "Managed":

[image]

But this is a native x86 C++ project:

[image]

**update:** I've deduced that this is *not* the cause of my problem (now resolved) so the question is simply why processes that are purely native C++ (they pre-date .NET) are detected as managed?

Comment: It would be possible that a library you link to embeddeds the runtime and this confuses the debuggger. But I would first check whether the (expected) unmanaged debugger works as it should. Does debugging in native mode work?

Comment: @AlexF my dev-PC is not the build server. I am using versions produced in the official built. One thing I can never remember - is the PDB loaded from the debug target, or the machine running VS?

Comment: Thanks @AlexF. So the problem was nothing to do with managed/native but I'm still interested in the original question. How does the debugger detect this?